# Explict wait doesnot work consistently, fails giving error other element is receiving the click

Tags: java, selenium

I am using a page object model,

**My Firefox version is 47.01 and Selenium Server version is 2.53.1**

**Error I get while testNG execution:**

> FAILED: startTest org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Element is
>   not clickable at point (1258, 50). Other element would receive the
>   click:  Command duration or timeout: 79
>   milliseconds

**Below are the things I have already tried:**

1. waiting for the element that is giving error.
   **Result :** wait still fails.
2. Putting break point and debugging.
   **Result:** Same code absolutely works fine without errors in debug mode.
3. Have tried with Implict wait. 
   **Result:** Again, fails in the execution while works fine in debug mode.

**My Wait code In Test_Base class, where wait is declared:**

```
public void waitForElement(Wait<WebDriver> wait){

    System.out.println("#####Insidewait");

    if(wait == null){
    //this.wait = new WebDriverWait(myBrowser, 20);

        this.wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(myBrowser)
                //Timeout time is set to 20
                .withTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                // polling interval
                .pollingEvery(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                //ignore the exception
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotVisibleException.class);
    }
}
```

**Test_Script001 class extends the Test_Base class, where the wait object is used:**

```
By upgrade = By.xpath("//a[text()='Upgrade']");
By loader = By.xpath("//div[@id='dashBoardLoader'and contains(@style,'display: block')]");
By logout = By.xpath("//a[text() = 'Logout']");
Home home = null;
LogIN login = null;@Test
public void startTest() throws Exception {

    login.loginToApplication(repository.getProperty("username"), repository.getProperty("password"));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(loader));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(upgrade)).isDisplayed();
    WebElement btnUpgrade = myBrowser.findElement(upgrade);
    if(btnUpgrade.isDisplayed()){
        //myBrowser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        home.ClickOnLogout();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlContains(logoutURL));
        System.out.println("Clicked on logout successfully..");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Unable to click on logout.");
}
```

Comment: Since wait is not effectively working for me, is there a new way to do this or is there way way to make the wait work for me.. i.e actually wait for few seconds.

Comment: Have you tried with ExepctedConditions.elementToBeClickable(....)

Comment: @Grasshopper, yes..

Comment: infact 
1. ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(previousElement)
2. ExpectedConditions.presenceofElement(..)
3. ExpectedCondition.elementToBeClickable(..)

Comment: What is the difference between the way you execute this in debug mode vs real time? Do you go over it step by step? It might be a timing issue.

Comment: @Sai, Right..Thats why, I am using Explict wait (Fluent wait). thats my suspect too and some how wait is not working for me.. My Firefox version is 47.01 and Selenium Server version is 2.53.1

Comment: Is the max wait time sufficient?

Comment: Additionally, try surrounding your fluent wait with a try catch block and see if there are any exceptions thrown there. Might give you an indication of any errors you need to handle before performing the click

Comment: Did you tried adding thread.sleep(); before the click on the particular element.?

Comment: @Sai, have tried upto 30 seconds and visibly.. the element does not take that long to appear.. nor the browser hangs..

Comment: @AnurajR.. i feel thread.sleep() is not an efficient way of waiting.. hence did not use. 

exception handling ? None are there..

Comment: Try by changing the locator. There may be an other element overlapping on the element that you are trying to click on.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely a timing issue. The expectation `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated` doesn't  really wait for the visiblility. It waits for the element to be displayed with a positive size and opacity, but the element could still be covered by another one.

To overcome this issue, you can retry to click until success:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until((WebDriver drv) -> {
    try {
        element.click();
        return true;
    } catch (WebDriverException ex) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

You could also try to wait for a specific size if your element is displayed with some transition effects:

```
// wait minimum width / height
new WebDriverWait(driver, 6).until((WebDriver drv) -> {
    Dimension size = element.getSize();
    return size.getWidth() > 15 && size.getHeight() > 15 ? element : null;
}).click();
```

Comment: You were right.. the functions earlier used in combination with ExpectedConditions were returning status based on rendering from server and hence, wait was immediately returning true from DOM status; rather than waiting for sometime and then returning true. I used a work around of using attributesToBe function; which checks for the changes in the attributes of HTML tags once DOM is loaded.. Worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this a number of times. It's typically after closing a dialog that has a modal (gray) background that doesn't close quite fast enough, etc. What I do is chain a couple waits together, I wait for the modal background (or whatever) to be invisible and then wait for the element to be clickable/visible.

The error message should tell you what element would receive the click... that's the one you want to wait to be invisible.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(locator)); // blocking element
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator)).click(); // desired element
```

Answer (score 0):

All, thanks a lot for the help..

My Application had controls rendered from server on DOM but the visibility of the element was being controlled in the client side, using CSS attributes such as display: block and display: none.

**I was using functions that used to check for element to be present in the DOM (server rendering) and hence wait was returning true and  synchronization failing; While I was assuming that wait was failing !**

Solved the wait timing issue by using client side attribute's function

**ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe (locator, attribute, value);**

i.e **instead of**

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(element));

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(element)).isDisplayed();

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceofElement(element)).isDisplayed();

**used**

ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe (locator, attribute, value);